# Creating a tree view in javascript with interactive content

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, client-server

I'm trying to create a tree view of a hierarchical data model. My goal is that i can click on the elements of the tree and edit their attributes. The data model is stored on the server and has already a logic layer for accessing it. The data model would be contributed to several users.

Which framework / lib is the best for my purpose? In my opinion, my Front-End won't need much logic. Basically sending commands to the server and display the retrieved data.

After some research I would stick with angular. Also because I could use TypeScript with it. But I don't know what I should use for the interactive tree.

Does it make sense to use Angular, or should I stick to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at :

- Angular Tree Component https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component
- NG2 tree https://valor-software.com/ng2-tree/index.html